Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32 ASP.NET Core MVC
I have a view that searches a SQL database and shows results, when I click on the edit link it should take me to a page to update the information. Instead, I get this error message

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32.

I have tried changing out the stored procedure which didn't work. I'm not using GetInt32 anywhere in my program. In my stored procedure the parameter is the RQKey which is an int not big or small so there shouldn't be any conversion needed. Not sure why the program is throwing this error. Any help is appreciated.
Controller:
public IActionResult Update(int id)
{
    Request reqs = new Request();

    try
    {
        reqs = GetRequest(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return View(reqs);
}
    
public IActionResult UpdateRequests(Request updatereq)
{
   string ConnectionString = connectionStrings.Get("EquipmentConnectString");

   var objConnect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
   var objReqDataSet = new DataSet();
   string UpdateQuery = "sp_UpdateRequest9";

   try
   {
     var objcommandUpdate = new SqlCommand(UpdateQuery, objConnect);
     objcommandUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     //Add Parameters
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowCount", 1);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RQKey", updatereq.Rqkey);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", updatereq.Address1);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", updatereq.Address2);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address3", updatereq.Address3);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ag_ID", updatereq.AgId);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ag_Guid", updatereq.AgGuid);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ag_Name", updatereq.AgName);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApprovalDate", updatereq.ApprovalDate);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Approved", updatereq.Approved);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApprovedBy", updatereq.ApprovedBy);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuditComments", updatereq.AuditComments);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuditDate", updatereq.AuditDate);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseNum", updatereq.CaseNum);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", updatereq.City);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Closed", updatereq.Closed);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", updatereq.Comments);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Convictions", updatereq.Convictions);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CriminalActivity", updatereq.CriminalActivity);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAgencyReceived", updatereq.DateAgencyReceived);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAgencyReturned", updatereq.DateAgencyReturned);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateDueBack", updatereq.DateDueBack);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateExtendedUntil", updatereq.DateExtendedUntil);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateIssued", updatereq.DateIssued);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateNeededFrom", updatereq.DateNeededFrom);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateNeededTo", updatereq.DateNeededTo);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateReturnReceived", updatereq.DateReturnReceived);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBEntry", updatereq.Dbentry);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disapproval", updatereq.Disapproval);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", updatereq.Email);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extend", updatereq.Extend);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtendApprovalDate", updatereq.ExtendApprovalDate);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtendApprovedBy", updatereq.ExtendApprovedBy);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtendComments", updatereq.ExtendComments);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtendDisapproval", updatereq.ExtendDisapproval);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtendReason", updatereq.ExtendReason);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellNumber", updatereq.CellNumber);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Intel", updatereq.Intel);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LECCode", updatereq.Leccode);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LECName", updatereq.Lecname);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Officer", updatereq.Officer);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Refer", updatereq.Refer);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqId", updatereq.ReqId);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestAmt", updatereq.RequestAmt);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestDate", updatereq.RequestDate);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Results", updatereq.Results);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultsDate", updatereq.ResultsDate);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceType", updatereq.ServiceType);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", updatereq.State);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Technician", updatereq.Technician);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Useage", updatereq.Useage);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VoiceNumber", updatereq.VoiceNumber);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", updatereq.Zip);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zzCreationDate", updatereq.ZzCreationDate);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zzUpdateDate", updatereq.ZzUpdateDate);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zzUserCreated", updatereq.ZzUserCreated);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zzUserLastUpdated", updatereq.ZzUserLastUpdated);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@audioenhancements", updatereq.AudioEnhancements);
     objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@videoenhancements", updatereq.VideoEnhancements);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", updatereq.County);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndividualsLocated", updatereq.IndividualsLocated);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CasesResolved", updatereq.CasesResolved);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CasesProsecuted", updatereq.CasesProsecuted);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RetrievedAV", updatereq.RetrievedAv);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourtDate", updatereq.CourtDate);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqsToCourtroom", updatereq.ReqsToCourtroom);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnSiteVisits", updatereq.OnSiteVisits);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewEvidences", updatereq.NewEvidences);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NonCaseAVServices", updatereq.NonCaseAvservices);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Consultations", updatereq.Consultations);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MediumsAnalyzed", updatereq.MediumsAnalyzed);
      objcommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VolumeDataAnalyzedGB", updatereq.VolumeDataAnalyzedGb);

       var objDataAdpater = new SqlDataAdapter(objcommandUpdate);
       objDataAdpater.Fill(objReqDataSet, "Request"); //EquipmentV2 Request table
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       throw ex;
     }

     return Redirect("Index/" + updatereq.Rqkey); 
}

private Request GetRequest(int id)
{
    string ConnectionString = connectionStrings.Get("EquipmentConnectString");

    var objConnect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    var objReqDataSet = new DataSet();
    string GetQuery = "GetEquipmentRequest";

    try
    {
        var objCommand = new SqlCommand(GetQuery, objConnect);
        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objCommand.CommandTimeout = 360;

        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RQKey", id);

        var objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
        objDataAdapter.Fill(objReqDataSet, "Request"); //EquipmentV2 Request table
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    Request Detailsrq = new Request();
    DataRow row = objReqDataSet.Tables["Request"].Rows[0];

    if (row["RQKey"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.Rqkey = 0;
    else 
        Detailsrq.Rqkey = (int)row["RQKey"];

    if (row["RequestDate"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.RequestDate = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.RequestDate = (System.DateTime)row["RequestDate"];

    if (row["ApprovedBy"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.ApprovedBy = "";
    else 
        Detailsrq.ApprovedBy = (string)row["ApprovedBy"];

    if (row["ApprovalDate"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.ApprovalDate = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.ApprovalDate = (System.DateTime)row["ApprovalDate"];

    if (row["ServiceType"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.ServiceType = "";
    else 
        Detailsrq.ServiceType = (string)row["ServiceType"];

    if (row["Technician"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.Technician = "";
    else 
        Detailsrq.Technician = (string)row["Technician"];

    if (row["CriminalActivity"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.CriminalActivity = "";
    else 
        Detailsrq.CriminalActivity = (string)row["CriminalActivity"];

    if (row["CaseNum"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.CaseNum = "";
    else 
        Detailsrq.CaseNum = (string)row["CaseNum"];

    if (row["DateNeededFrom"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.DateNeededFrom = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.DateNeededFrom = (System.DateTime)row["DateNeededFrom"];

    if (row["DateNeededTo"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.DateNeededTo = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.DateNeededTo = (System.DateTime)row["DateNeededTo"];

    if (row["DateIssued"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.DateIssued = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.DateIssued = (System.DateTime)row["DateIssued"];

    if (row["DateDueBack"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.DateDueBack = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.DateDueBack = (System.DateTime)row["DateDueBack"];

    if (row["ExtendApprovalDate"] is DBNull)  
        Detailsrq.ExtendApprovalDate = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.ExtendApprovalDate = (System.DateTime)row["ExtendApprovalDate"];

    if (row["DateAgencyReceived"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.DateAgencyReceived = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.DateAgencyReceived = (System.DateTime)row["DateAgencyReceived"];

    if (row["DateAgencyReturned"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.DateAgencyReturned = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.DateAgencyReturned = (System.DateTime)row["DateAgencyReturned"];

    if (row["Comments"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.Comments = "";
    else 
        Detailsrq.Comments = (string)row["Comments"];

    if (row["Disapproval"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.Disapproval = "";
    else 
        Detailsrq.Disapproval = (string)row["Disapproval"];

    if (row["ResultsDate"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.ResultsDate = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.ResultsDate = (System.DateTime)row["ResultsDate"];

    if (row["CourtDate"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.CourtDate = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else 
        Detailsrq.CourtDate = (System.DateTime)row["CourtDate"];

    if (row["Results"] is DBNull)  
        Detailsrq.Results = "";
    else 
        Detailsrq.Results = (string)row["Results"];

    if (row["Dbentry"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.Dbentry = 0;
    else 
        Detailsrq.Dbentry = (int)row["Dbentry"];

    if (row["AudioEnhancements"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.AudioEnhancements = 0;
    else 
        Detailsrq.AudioEnhancements = (int)row["AudioEnhancements"];

    if (row["ReqsToCourtroom"] is DBNull) 
        Detailsrq.ReqsToCourtroom = 0;
    else 
        Detailsrq.ReqsToCourtroom = (int)row["ReqsToCourtroom"];

    if (row["Convictions"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Convictions = 0;
    else Detailsrq.Convictions = (int)row["Convictions"];

    if (row["VideoEnhancements"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.VideoEnhancements = 0;
    else Detailsrq.VideoEnhancements = (int)row["VideoEnhancements"];

    if (row["OnSiteVisits"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.OnSiteVisits = 0;
    else Detailsrq.OnSiteVisits = (int)row["OnSiteVisits"];

    if (row["IndividualsLocated"] is DBNull)    Detailsrq.IndividualsLocated = 0;
    else Detailsrq.IndividualsLocated = (int)row["IndividualsLocated"];

    if (row["RetrievedAv"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.RetrievedAv = 0;
    else Detailsrq.RetrievedAv = (int)row["RetrievedAv"];

    if (row["NewEvidences"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.NewEvidences = 0;
    else Detailsrq.NewEvidences = (int)row["NewEvidences"];

    if (row["CasesResolved"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.CasesResolved = 0;
    else Detailsrq.CasesResolved = (int)row["CasesResolved"];

    if (row["MediumsAnalyzed"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.MediumsAnalyzed = 0;
    else Detailsrq.MediumsAnalyzed = (int)row["MediumsAnalyzed"];

    if (row["NonCaseAvservices"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.NonCaseAvservices = 0;
    else Detailsrq.NonCaseAvservices = (int)row["NonCaseAvservices"];

    if (row["CasesProsecuted"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.CasesProsecuted = 0;
    else Detailsrq.CasesProsecuted = (int)row["CasesProsecuted"];

    if (row["VolumeDataAnalyzedGb"] is DBNull)   Detailsrq.VolumeDataAnalyzedGb = 0;
    else Detailsrq.VolumeDataAnalyzedGb = (int)row["VolumeDataAnalyzedGb"];

    if (row["Consultations"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Consultations = 0;
    else Detailsrq.Consultations = (int)row["Consultations"];

    if (row["Intel"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Intel = 0;
    else Detailsrq.Intel = (byte)row["Intel"];

    if (row["Refer"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Refer = 0;
    else Detailsrq.Refer = (byte)row["Refer"];

    if (row["ReqId"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.ReqId = "";
    else Detailsrq.ReqId = (string)row["ReqId"];

    if (row["ag_Name"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.AgName = "";
    else Detailsrq.AgName = (string)row["ag_Name"];

    if (row["Officer"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Officer = "";
    else Detailsrq.Officer = (string)row["Officer"];

    if (row["Address1"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Address1 = "";
    else Detailsrq.Address1 = (string)row["Address1"];

    if (row["Address2"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Address2 = "";
    else Detailsrq.Address2 = (string)row["Address2"];

    if (row["Address3"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Address3 = "";
    else Detailsrq.Address3 = (string)row["Address3"];

    if (row["City"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.City = "";
    else Detailsrq.City = (string)row["City"];

    if (row["State"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.State = "";
    else Detailsrq.State = (string)row["State"];

    if (row["Zip"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Zip = "";
    else Detailsrq.Zip = (string)row["Zip"];

    if (row["Email"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.Email = "";
    else Detailsrq.Email = (string)row["Email"];

    if (row["County"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.County = "";
    else Detailsrq.County = (string)row["County"];

    if (row["VoiceNumber"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.VoiceNumber = "";
    else Detailsrq.VoiceNumber = (string)row["VoiceNumber"];

    if (row["CellNumber"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.CellNumber = "";
    else Detailsrq.CellNumber = (string)row["CellNumber"];

    if (row["ExtendApprovedBy"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.ExtendApprovedBy = "";
    else Detailsrq.ExtendApprovedBy = (string)row["ExtendApprovedBy"];

    if (row["ExtendApprovalDate"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.ExtendApprovalDate = System.DateTime.MinValue;
    else Detailsrq.ExtendApprovalDate = (System.DateTime)row["ExtendApprovalDate"];

    if (row["ExtendReason"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.ExtendReason = "";
    else Detailsrq.ExtendReason = (string)row["ExtendReason"];

    if (row["ExtendComments"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.ExtendComments = "";
    else Detailsrq.ExtendComments = (string)row["ExtendComments"];

    if (row["ExtendDisapproval"] is DBNull) Detailsrq.ExtendDisapproval = "";
    else Detailsrq.ExtendDisapproval = (string)row["ExtendDisapproval"];

    return Detailsrq;
}

View:
@model SearchContact
<body>
<form asp-action="ContactPages" asp-controller="Contacts" method="post">
    <div class="full-width">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h6>Contact Search</h6>
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="3" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="padding:4pt">
                    Type:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <select asp-for="Type">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="Brand">Brand</option>
                        <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="padding:4pt">
                    Brand/Vendor Name:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="text" id="brandvenName" asp-for="CompanyName"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="padding:4pt">
                    Contact Name:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="text" id="ContactName" asp-for="ContactName"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="padding-right:4pt">
                    State:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <select asp-for="State">
                        @{
                            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/StateListAbbr.cshtml");
                        }
                    </select>
                   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        <br />
        <a asp-action="AddContact" asp-controller="Contacts">Add Contact</a>
    </div>
</form>
@if (Model.Contacts != null && Model.Contacts.Any())
{
    <br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:75%;
    background-color:white; border:1px solid black;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Brand/Vendor Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Contact Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Purchase Note</th>
                <th>Support Note</th>
                <th><!--Edit--></th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var con in Model.Contacts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@con.EntityName</td>
                <td>@con.EntityType</td>
                <td>@con.ContactName</td>
                <td>@con.City</td>
                <td>@con.State</td>
                <td>@con.NotePurchase</td>
                <td>@con.NoteSupport</td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="UpdateContactPage" asp-route-id="@con.Ctvdkey">Edit</a>
                </td>
                
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}

<style>
    .body-container {
        /*remove the container default padding attribute*/
        /*padding-left: 0px !important;
                                padding-right: 0px !important;*/
        /*increase width as per your need*/
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</body>


This question is similar to: Casting from 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

that other question isn't similar to mine. I've made edits to the original post

I found a column that was using smallint instead of int in my SQL database. Changing this column to int fixed my issue and I can now click on the edit link and it works.
